# Why I cant append tempDF to df?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have that code:

```
def show_files(upload_files):

    tempDF = pd.DataFrame()
    tempDF2 = pd.DataFrame()

    for file in upload_files:
        file = file.name
        if file.startswith('L'):
            Table = Dbf5(file)
            DF1 = Table.to_dataframe()
            tempDF = tempDF.append(DF1, sort=False)

        elif file.startswith('M'):
            Table = Dbf5(file)
            DF2 = Table.to_dataframe()
            tempDF2 = tempDF2.append(DF2, sort=False)
            print(f"final 2 - {tempDF2}")

  return [tempDF, tempDF2]
```

Upload_files it's a list with filenames. Example:

```
["M22.dbf", "M31.dfb", "L22.dfb"]
```

All dbf are succesfully loaded as DF. I debuged it. So `DF1 = Table.to_dataframe()` works fine. But function return DF only from last loaded file...

For example:

```
1. Load M22 (500rows)
2. Put in TEMP_DF2 (temp_df2 = 500rows)
3. Load M31 (266rows)
4. Put in TEMP_DF2 with append(temp_DF2 = 266 rows, excepted 766)
```

And I have no idea why? I can't notice a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your `DataFrame` looks like and , however, the issue seems not to be the append (see example below). Could it be an issue with the passed list? An full example to reproduce your error might help.

```py
import pandas as pd

uploads = ['M1', 'M2', 'L1', 'L2', 'M3']

df_m = pd.DataFrame()
df_l = pd.DataFrame()

for upload in uploads:
    if upload.lower().startswith('l'):
        df_l = df_l.append(pd.DataFrame({'a' : [i for i in range(10)]}))
    else:
        df_m = df_m.append(pd.DataFrame({'a' : [i for i in range(10)]}))

print('M: ', df_m.shape) #(30,1)
print('L: ', df_l.shape) #(20,1)
```